# How can I get no-injected-class-name from clang::ParmVarDecl without using std::string operation

Tags: c++, compilation, clang, llvm, clang-tidy

The parameter type is a Record and I have no idea to get the no-injected-class-name from clang::ParmVarDecl without using std::string operation.

```
struct A{};
void showA(const A& a) {}
```

I get "**const struct A&**" by invoking "**ParmVarDecl->getOriginalType()->getAsString**". But I want "**const A&**".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also if this is anyhow related to clang-tidy, please specify what check are you referring to and what errors (if any) are you getting.